# Time : Getting time in millisecond for a future date/time

Tags: c

Is there a better, cleaner way to get time in milliseconds for a future time? For example how to find time in milliseconds for tomorrow @ 11:00:00?

I am doing something like following:

```
struct tm * start_tm;
time_t rawtime;
time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime_r ( &rawtime, &start_tm );
start_tm.tm_sec = 00; start_tm.tm_min = 00; start_tm.tm_hour = 11;
time_t s = mktime(&start_tm);
```

Comment: `time in mil-seconds for tomorrow @ 11:00:00?` I would assume that tomorrow exactly at 11:00:00 the milliseconds part will always be zero. How can it not be zero? It's exactly 11:00:00. Or do you want to get time _until_ tomorrow 11:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `time_t` supports sub-seconds ...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  time_t now;
  if (time(&now) == -1) Handle_Error();

  struct tm now_tm;
  if (localtime_r(&now, &now_tm) == NULL) Handle_Error();

  struct tm start_tm = { 0 };  // Important to initialize to 0
  // Assign the key 7 members, rest are 0, including a potential sub-second one
  start_tm.tm_year = now_tm.tm_year;
  start_tm.tm_mon = now_tm.tm_mon;
  start_tm.tm_mday = now_tm.tm_mday + 1;
  start_tm.tm_isdst = -1;  // Let mktime determine tomorrow's DST setting
  start_tm.tm_hour = 11;
  start_tm.tm_min = 0;
  start_tm.tm_sec = 0;
  // Do not copy optional sub-second members

  time_t start = mktime(&start_tm);
  if (start == -1) Handle_Error();

  double diff = difftime(start, now);
  printf("Starting in %.3f seconds\n", diff);
}

// Sample output
Starting in 86752.000 seconds
```

If `time_t` does not supports sub-seconds ...

You need an implementation specific solution or settle with the above always printing "x.000".

Comment: Is there a system where `time_t` supports sub-second timing?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes.  Which SE site, if not SO, do you think is best to ask about implementation details in C that have been seen / currently in use?